# ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects in Android Termux

Tags: termux, python

I'm trying to install numpy in Termux in Android and I'm getting this error :

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

And got this error :

```
 CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/apt/methods/https": library "libssl.so.1.1" not found
```

The second error happened the second time i run `apt update && apt upgrade`
is there any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a [recent discussion on this subject](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/10808#issuecomment-1137229251).

To install the up to date version of numpy (1.22.4), simply run

```
MATHLIB="m" pip install numpy
```

And numpy wheel will be build normally.

Your second error (with `[...]/https`) seems an Internet connection problem, but not sure.